# Using functions outside an IIFE function

Tags: javascript, function, iife

I have the following method, it is inside a someFile.js:

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
        define(['b'], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        // Node. Does not work with strict CommonJS, but
        // only CommonJS-like environments that support module.exports,
        // like Node.
        module.exports = factory(require('b'));
    } else {
        // Browser globals (root is window)
        root.returnExports = factory(root.b);
    }
}(this, function (b) {
    //use b in some fashion.

    // Just return a value to define the module export.
    // This example returns an object, but the module
    // can return a function as the exported value.

        b.isValid = function(parameter){
            if (!isString(parameter)){
                return false;
            }
            parameter = this.newFormat(parameter);
            return parameter;
        };

}));
```

As a IIFE function, it will invoke itself automatically, but then, what I want to do in a separate JavaScript file, is to use that method, something like:

```
b.isValid('value to test');
```

Is this possible? Or how is the best solution to access or call those functions from outside of this IIFE function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could assign it to `window['b']` or return it to a variable outside of the IIFE?

Comment: Are you using UMD only by accident?

Comment: Just use the exact same pattern and it will magically work. You're adding a method to the global `b` module after importing it, and you can import it in other files in the exact same way.

Comment: I don't think mutating (or extending) a dependency this way is a good idea (unless `b` is some library and `module` is some plugin or something similar)

Answer (score -1):

You can return some value from the factory function which will then get assigned to the `exports` object or root (or whatever)...

E.g. **module.js**

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
            // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
            define(['dependency'], factory);
        } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
            // Node. Does not work with strict CommonJS, but
            // only CommonJS-like environments that support module.exports,
            // like Node.
            module.exports = factory(require('dependency'));
        } else {
            // Browser globals (root is window)
            root['identifier']= factory(root['dependency']);
        }
    })(this, function (dep) {

        // Just return a value to define the module export.
        // This example returns an object, but the module
        // can return a function as the exported value.

        return {
           fn: function(){
                console.log([].slice.call(arguments))
            }
        }

    });
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="module.js"></script>
<!-- Module will be executed in the global context and it's value will be assigned to the window object -->
<script>
    // can access the module's export here
    window['identifier'].fn('something', 'goes', 'here')
    // or, preferred way would be: identifier.fn('something', 'goes', 'here')
</script>
```

or inside **some_other_module.js**

```
// CommonJS
var depX = require("./module.js")  // can omit .js extension
depX.fn('something', 'goes', 'here')

// es6
import depX from "./module.js"  // can omit .js extension
depX.fn('something', 'goes', 'here')
```